# profiling knockoutjs mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using knockout-2.1 with version 2.3.2 of the mapping plugin. My concern is that the mapping plugin is often quite slow to evaluate. I instrumented one of my object creation methods, but that only accounted for about 10% of the total time. My guess is that it is not deferring updates properly but I am not sure. I would like to profile the call, but am not sure what the best way to do that is.

Does anyone have a good example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO: `ko.mapping` is just a plugin to **simplify** converting simple object (more often server side model) to knockout view model.

When things become more **complex**, you may consider do the mapping your own.

I myself used to use `ko.mapping` everywhere, but after the `create` and `update` grows bigger and bigger, my code become unreadable. So i decided to refactor my code, it turns out that it's easier than i thought.(may be you need something like `_.clone`).

PS: you should paste the code, it may not be `ko.mapping`'s fault.